# Ошибка при десериализации JSON с помощью Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

Пока разбираюсь именно с Jersey, поэтому не предлагайте другие библиотеки.

Итак, хочу получать с сайта курсы валют ([НБУ](https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json)) и превращать их в объекты.

Сразу оговорюсь, что в формате `XML` все работает. Не работает именно `JSON`.
Образец взял [отсюда](https://o7planning.org/ru/11217/create-java-restful-client-with-jersey-client#a4484419).

```
package misc.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

import java.util.List;

public class CurrenciesJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

        // Create Client based on Config
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

        WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json");

        Builder builder = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) //
                .header("content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        ClientResponse response = builder.get(ClientResponse.class);

        // Status 200 is successful.
        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            System.out.println("Failed with HTTP Error code: " + response.getStatus());
            String error = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("Error: " + error);
            return;
        }

        GenericType<List<Currency>> generic = new GenericType<List<Currency>>() {
            // No thing
        };

        List<Currency> list = response.getEntity(generic);

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");

        for (Currency currency : list) {
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(currency);
        }
    }
}
```

Entity

```
package misc.jersey;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Currency {
    private int r030;
    private String txt;
    private double rate;
    private String cc;
    private String exchangedate;

    public Currency() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Currency{" +
                "r030=" + r030 +
                ", txt='" + txt + '\'' +
                ", rate=" + rate +
                ", cc='" + cc + '\'' +
                ", exchangedate=" + exchangedate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Exception:
`Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 10; unexpected element (uri:"", local:"r030"). Expected elements are <{}currency>]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractListElementProvider.java:355) etc...`

Если поменять адрес запроса на `https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?xml` и в заголовке на `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`, то работает!

В чем проблема? Что за `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"r030")`?

Comment: Аргументы за минус? Или ты - бот?

Comment: в ошибке же написано, что вместо ожидаемого поля `currency ` на вход парсеру приходит `r030`, проверьте свои POJO классы в модели

Comment: В модели не может быть причина, т.к. с xml отрабатывает нормально

Comment: попробуйте убрать в модели JAXB аннотации `@XmlRootElement()` и `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`

Comment: @mit тогда ошибка `SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class java.util.List, and Java type java.util.List<stackOverflow.jsonParse.Entity>, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found`

Comment: Проблема вот в чем: мой `response.getEntity()` ожидает не просто массив `JSON`-ов (`[{"field1":"value1"},{"field2":"value2"},{"field3":"value3"}...]`), а так сказать именованный массив: `currency:[{"field1":"value1"},{"field2":"value2"},{"field3":"value3"}...]`. А как это побороть - не знаю...

Comment: добавьте пакет `jersey-json` в зависимости

Comment: почему именнованный массив? По вашей ссылке приходит обычный валидный массив из JSON объектов

Comment: Приходит - да. А ожидается JSON-элемент с именем `currency` и массивом. Как указать, что это не элемент, а массив?

Comment: убрать аннотации и добавить jersey-json в maven зависимости, тогда парсер сам все распарсит

Comment: Пробовал всё, не выходит. Почитал, что зависит от апп сервера. Tomcat, например, и GlassFish по-разному парсят...

Comment: я бы рекомендовал вам, сразу, начать изучение jersey со 2 версии. Ваш пример по 1 версии. Между ними, насколько я помню большие различия.

Comment: Методом проб и ошибок я добился генерирования `JSON` без названия массива. Нужно было добавлять в `web.xml` параметр `<init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>`. Но у меня задача обратная и у меня простой проект, без `web.xml`. Тупик...